# How to use iMessages without giving out phone number?

Tags: icloud, messages

I want students to text me at iCloud and I want to receive the messages on my iPhone and reply to them by iCloud. In essence, I don’t want them to have my personal phone number.

Comment: Why not get a Google voice number?  You will receive the text messages on your iPhone (or any other device for that matter) via the app.

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Answer (score 5):

You can enable the iCloud email address under Settings → Messages → Send & Receive. After which just tell your students to compose a new message to your email address. They can even maintain your contact in their address books with only your email, not number.

Also, to prevent accidentally giving out your number, use email address to compose new messages. This setting can be found in the same place.

Comment: Yes, either solution will work. With the iCloud address i was concerned that they would not realize that they were texting and just give up and use my university email instead.